# Can't invoke "upload" using SwiftyDropbox

Tags: swift, dropbox, dropbox-api, swiftydropbox

I just started iOS development and I'm using the Dropbox API with SwiftyDropbox. I'm trying to upload a text file to dropbox but I'm getting the following error:

Cannot invoke 'upload' with an argument list of type '(path: String)'

Here is my code. What am I doing wrong?

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    if let authResult = DropboxClientsManager.handleRedirectURL(url) {
        switch authResult {
        case .success:
            print("Logged into Dropbox successfully.")
        case .cancel:
            print("Authorization canceled.")
        case .error(_, let description):
            print("Error: \(description)")


        }

        let client = DropboxClientsManager.authorizedClient

        client.files.upload(path: "/hello.txt").response { response, error in
            if let metadata = response {
                println("Uploaded file name: \(metadata.name)")
                println("Uploaded file revision: \(metadata.rev)")

        let client = DropboxClientsManager.authorizedClient
        client?.files.createFolderV2(path: "/Auction_Upload").response { response, error in
            if let response = response {
                print(response)
            } else if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can´t do it the way that you have done it. In the `path` filed you need to add the path to where you want to add the file. Then you need to pass the content. Do it like this instead:

```
let client = DropboxClientsManager.authorizedClient
let fileData = "Some test text to upload".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!

let request = client?.files.upload(path: "/test/path/in/Dropbox/account", input: fileData)
    .response { response, error in
        if let response = response {
            print(response)
        } else if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    .progress { progressData in
        print(progressData)
}
```

Comment: The app builds successfully but nothing is being uploaded to Dropbox. Here is the console output: Logged into Dropbox successfully.
<NSProgress: 0x6040001267c0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 1.0000 / Completed: 24 of 24  
[request-id fe7db8319492813845ec1c1821f4925e] API route error - {
    ".tag" = path;
    reason =     {
        ".tag" = conflict;
        conflict =         {
            ".tag" = folder;
        };
    };
    "upload_session_id" = AAAAAAAAAgA4CFfnEC8d6Q;
}

Comment: @vipertherapper, did you make sure that the path exists?

Comment: Yes. The path exists.

Comment: I added a filename to the path "/test/path/in/Dropbox/account/test.txt" and the upload worked fine. I also specified using .overwrite inside of my request. Thanks for your help.